# Implicit encoder for a trait type parameter

Tags: json, scala, traits, argonaut

I would like to encode to json a field of type `List[E]` using argonaut lib.

```scala
sealed trait Msg[E] {
  val contents: List[E]    

  def send(): Unit = {
    val json = contents.asJson
    println("Sending json: " + json.toString())
  }
}
```

Then I have a `StringMsg` case class:

```scala
case class StringMsg(contents: List[String]) extends Msg[String]
```

The argonaut lib defines the `JsonIdentity[J]` trait:

```scala
trait JsonIdentity[J] {
  val j: J

  /**
   * Encode to a JSON value using the given implicit encoder.
   */
  def jencode(implicit e: EncodeJson[J]): Json =
    e(j)
}
```

When I create a new instance of `StringMsg` and call the `send()` method, I have the following error:

```scala
StringMsg(List("a","b")).send()
```

> could not find implicit value for parameter e:
>   argonaut.EncodeJson[List[E]]

Comment: I've never tried this lib but looking at the [doc](http://argonaut.io/scaladocs/index.html#argonaut.EncodeJson$) it seems you have to `import argonaut.EncodeJson._`. No?

Comment: No the import does not solve the problem. The type parameter E should be resolved to String in order to use an encoder like EncodeJson[List[String]], i think i have to deal with the type erasure or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your API should require implicit `argonaut.EncodeJson[List[E]]` from client code:

```
sealed trait Msg[E] {
  val contents: List[E]
  implicit def encodeJson: argonaut.EncodeJson[List[E]] //to be implemented in subclass   

  def send(): Unit = {
    val json = contents.asJson
    println("Sending json: " + json.toString())
  }
}

//or

abstract class Msg[E](implicit encodeJson: argonaut.EncodeJson[List[E]]) {
  val contents: List[E]

  def send(): Unit = {
    val json = contents.asJson
    println("Sending json: " + json.toString())
  }
}

//or

sealed trait class Msg[E] {
  val contents: List[E]

  def send()(implicit encodeJson: argonaut.EncodeJson[List[E]]): Unit = {
    val json = contents.asJson
    println("Sending json: " + json.toString())
  }
}
```

Somewhere in the client-code:

```
case class StringMsg(contents: List[String]) extends Msg[String] { 
   implicit val encodeJson = argonaut.StringEncodeJson 
}

//or

import argonaut.StringEncodeJson //or even import argonaut._
case class StringMsg(contents: List[String]) extends Msg[String]() //implicit will be passed here

//or

import argonaut.StringEncodeJson //or even import argonaut._
case class StringMsg(contents: List[String]) extends Msg[String]
val a = StringMsg(Nil)
a.send() //implicit will be passed here
```